# wordpress editor role remove all but 'menus' in appearance menu

Tags: user-roles, editor, permissions, user-access

I'm trying to remove access to everything in the appearance menu in WP admin for the role editor. Or at the least, just remove access to themes and plugins. I have found how to remove the whole appearance menu but not parts of it like that. is this possible?

Preferably something in functions.php so I could toggle this on/off if ever I needed.

Answer (score 1):

by default the `editor` role should not have access to plugins nor appearance menu. But maybe this roles is already customised in your installation? here is a list of [editor default capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor)

via functions.php you can remove everything in the appearance menu like so:

```
$role_object = get_role( 'editor' );
$role_object->remove_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
```

to remove access to plugins you would have to remove some more capabilities i assume. `update_plugins`, `delete_plugins` and so on...

otherwise you could use a [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Plugins) to handle different roles comfortable. 
i do use adminimize quite a while.